# let D3js code knows current user name

Tags: php, wordpress, d3.js

I'm working with wordpress and my data content with D3js are user dependent.
Each user has a dedicated data directory and I would be able to choose the right one on the fly.
I known the current user_login in PHP but I don't know how to let D3js aware of that?

Comment: How can d3 be aware of user...you need to set some javascript variable holding the logged in user value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the variable in `PHP` you can simply pass it to `Javascript` like this.

```
<body>
    <script>
      var js_var = "<?php echo $userId; ?>";
        alert(js_var);
    </script>
</body>
```

Then you can use it in `d3` in anyway you like.

Comment: Because I'm new in wordpress and D3js bussiness, I can't make your code work.
I have some extensions to link javascript with D3 but in this case, I cant do it.

Comment: it seems that php is not executable in this context.

Comment: difficult to help without seeing the work you have tried.

Comment: I use wp-D3 to deal with D3js and I can add extra javascript by including them in wp-D3. But the question is: does this kind of javascript has the capability to execute php code ?
Your small code put directly in wp-D3 => php is not executable

Comment: `php` code does not executed in `js` file. When you render the `.php` file with `js` the PHP in that file et parsed before downloaded.

Comment: Let put the problem in an other view.
There are global wordpress variable like:
global $user_login
How to get this value in a wp-d3 file ?